# Ansible copy file to remote instance error

Tags: jenkins, ansible

I have a Ansible playbook that run by Jenkins on server A, all it does is to copy a file folder from server A to a remote server B:

The code looks like this:

```
- hosts: "{{ lookup('env', 'REMOTE_HOST') }}"
  any_errors_fatal: true # fail all hosts if any host fails
  become: true
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: root
  gather_facts: yes

  vars:

    date_time: "{{ lookup('env', 'DATE_TIME') }}"
    version_main: 10.7
    sql_dir: "~/code/data/sql/sql_data/{{ version_main }}"
    remote_files_directory: "~/deploy/{{ version_main }}/{{ date_time }}/files"

  tasks:  

    - name: "Copy SQL files from {{ sql_dir }} to {{ remote_files_directory }} on the remote host"
      become: yes
      become_user: user_a
      ansible.builtin.copy:
        src: "{{ sql_dir }}"
        dest: "{{ remote_files_directory }}"
        remote_src: true
```

All the SQL files are on server A, under user_a's home directory: `~/code/data/sql/sql_data/{{ version_main }}`, and I want to copy them to server B(REMOTE_HOST) under the same user_a's home: `~/deploy/{{ version_main }}/{{ date_time }}/files`

Variables REMOTE_HOST, DATE_TIME are from Jenkins.

The error I am getting with `remote_src: true` is:

```
[0;31 fatal: [server_B]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Source /home/user_a/code/data/sql/sql_data/10.7/ not found"}
```

If I set `remote_src: false`, I get this error:

```
[0;31 fatal: [server_B]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Could not find or access '~/code/data/sql/sql_data/10.7' on the Ansible Controller. If you are using a module and expect the file to exist on the remote, see the remote_src option"}
```

I even added the `delegate_to: "{{ lookup('env', 'DEPLOY_DATAMONTH_HOST') }}"` and it does not make any differences.

Somehow it can not figure out the source file folder on server A which is where the Ansible and Jenkins run.

This is the Ansible version I have on server A.

```
ansible --version
ansible [core 2.13.7]
```

Usser `jenkins` can not access `/home/user_a/code/data/sql/sql_data/10.7/`  directly, but `jenkins` can `sudo su - user_a`, so I think

```
become: yes
become_user: user_a
```

should have helped.

What am I still missing?

Comment: as best I can tell, you should omit the `become_user: user_a` and, as you pointed out, remove `remote_src: true` because the files are for sure not on `server B(REMOTE_HOST)`. Because your server-A playbook is already running as a privileged user, I would expect it can resolve user_a's files just fine, but you'll need to change `~/code` to `~user_a/code` because `~/` in your playbook is _root's_ home directory

Answer (score -1):

I believe that defining this at the host level with the following code block:

```
  become: true
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: root
```

takes priority over your attempt to become user_a in the tasks with the following code block:

```
      become: yes
      become_user: user_a
```